# How to correctly integrate FreeRadius and eDirectory for eduroam?

Tags: freeradius, peap, ttls

Does anyone have any experience implementing eduroam and integrating **Free-Radius** and **eDirectory**? If yes pleas share your experience on how to correctly configure both.
Also, do I have to **retrieve edirectory universal user password in clear text**, in order to make it compatible with **EAP-PEAP MSCHAP2** and **EAP-TTLS MSCHAP2**?

I've looked up numerous forums and wikis, but would like to hear from someone's personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but:

- yes, you'll need universal password (with retrieving passwords enabled) in order to play MSCHAPv2
- if you want to run your freeradius on linux, use SLES, not debian (for example) as there are a few needed modules missing